# What is the oldest published translation of the Lord's prayer into a Jewish (as opposed to Syriac) Aramaic dialect?

Tags: bible-translation, resource-request, translation, lords-prayer, aramaic

Not necessarily 1st century Galilean Aramaic, it can be the Imperial Aramaic used for parts of the book of Daniel, or the Targumic Aramaic used in the interpretive Jewish translations of Scripture.

But when does the first publication of a Lord's prayer translation in a distinctively Jewish (as opposed to Syriac) Aramaic dialect date back to, and what is the text?

I'm looking for it in Hebrew (square) letters with nikkud/vowel points

Comment: https://www.historian.net/10comm.html will be a useful reference site for you. Jack Kilmon has attempted a retro translation of the Lord's Prayer into Aramaic. One interesting theory is that it was originally said in verses !

Comment: http://www.historian.net/lp-pap2.html is the specific link.

Comment: See also my question on BHE https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/19878/our-father-in-heaven-prayer-prose-or-verse